# При выборе select выпадало значение

Tags: веб-программирование, html, javascript

Задача такая: человек выбирает из select какое-то значение, и в зависимости от этого значения выпадает value, умноженное на 2, например, <option value='31'>use 100500</option>
 в ф-ции значение value  -31- умножается на 2 и выводится результат, но у меня выводит вместо результата [object HTMLSelectElement].

```
     <div class="wrap">
Random value <input type="text" id="val2" /><br />
SELECT<form name="calcGame" action="">
<select id='val1' class="filtering" name="persons">
    <option value='0'>Ваш выбор</option>
    <option value='31'>use 100500</option>
    <option value='91'>why not 800</option>
    <option value='181'>i mean 777</option>
</select><br />     </form>

    <p class="total">Стоимость игры: 0 рублей</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var form = document.forms.calcGame;
        var persons = form.elements.persons;
        var total = document.querySelector('.total');
    function insertTotal() {
            var count =  persons*2;
            total.innerHTML =  count ;
        }
insertTotal();
```

**Обновление**

Посоветуйте какой-либо справочник по js, где был бы просто список функций с их описанием.

**Обновление 2**

Интересует, за что отвечает вот это - /\d+/. Пытаюсь немного отредактировать, но опять же перестаёт работать, если вставлять функцию:

```
{ 
function result (){/\d+/, this.value * 2};
total.innerHTML = total.innerHTML.replace( result();); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var form = document.forms.calcGame;
var persons = form.elements.persons;
var total = document.querySelector('.total');

persons.onchange = function()
{
    total.innerHTML = total.innerHTML.replace(/\d+/, this.value * 2);
}
</script>
```

**Обновление**

Блок:

```
function result (){/\d+/, this.value * 2};
total.innerHTML = total.innerHTML.replace( result(););
```

Отвечает за поиск и замену цифры. И не будет работать, так как нужно почитать хорошенько матчасть.

Comment: Если не сложно, подскажите,какую именно часть мат части?

Comment: @Виталина ♦ я думаю не нужно править ответы форумчан дописывая в них полную чепуху!

Answer (score 0):

[Список](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers-on-elements,-document-objects,-and-window-objects)  функций с описанием, также [справочник](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).